# Simple way to add foreach loop around WebClient

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, foreach, webclient

I have tried to add a `foreach` loop around a `WebClient` task, but it does not seem to work. I have done a bit of research and found that there are some clean dirty Methods to fix this like sending the system to sleep for one second, I would like a more structured solution. If there is no solution How else can I read a RSS feed from the internet with W8 phone.

```
foreach (string rssFeed in lstRSSFeeds)
{
    // our web downloader
    WebClient downloader = new WebClient();

    // our web address to download, notice the UriKind.Absolute
    Uri uri = new Uri(rssFeed, UriKind.Absolute);

    // we need to wait for the file to download completely, so lets hook the DownloadComplete Event
    downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(FileDownloadComplete);

    // start the download
    downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
}
```

Comment: Is this code sample complete, it doesn't appear you are using the rssFeed variable at all in the loop, so why the loop at all?

Comment: You said it "does not seem to work".  Are you getting a specific error message, or is it running to completion but not giving the desired results, or what?

Comment: Could it be that your actual problem is calling the async method of the WebClient inside a loop? I'm not sure about limitations on the WP8 platform but usually this can be solved using [await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx)

Comment: take a look at this previous `SO` posting not sure if it applies to what your are trying to do but looks like it may http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505967/multiple-parallel-execution-of-webclient-as-task-tpl

Comment: You're overriding `downloader` variable all the time.

Comment: @J.Marciniak He's not *overriding* it, no.  The variable is leaving scope and being re-declared in each iteration of the loop.  That is something different, and also not a problem at all.

Comment: @Servy yeah... you're right. I'm tried, sorry.

Comment: Don't forget that `WebClient` is disposable - so you need to dispose of your instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download multiple files, it would be best to implement some kind of download manager.  It might sound difficult, but I assure you it is not.

For example:

We can implement a Download Manager by creating a `List` of `KeyValuePair`.  The `KeyValuePair` will have a `Key` which is basically the Website's URL and `Value` of the Website's HTML (or downloaded content).

We will use your `foreach` scheme to download the files.

---

```C#
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    // our simple download manager
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> DownloadManager = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // create our list of websites to download
        List<string> lstRSSFeeds = new List<string>();

        // lets add 3 web sites
        lstRSSFeeds.Add("http://www.google.com");
        lstRSSFeeds.Add("http://www.msn.com");
        lstRSSFeeds.Add("http://www.chubosaurus.com");

        // for each website in the list, download its data
        foreach (string rssFeed in lstRSSFeeds)
        {
            // our web downloader
            WebClient downloader = new WebClient();

            // our web address to download, notice the UriKind.Absolute
            Uri uri = new Uri(rssFeed, UriKind.Absolute);
            downloader.BaseAddress = uri.ToString();

            // we need to wait for the file to download completely, so lets hook the DownloadComplete Event
            downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(FileDownloadComplete);

            // start the download
            downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
        }
    }

    // this event will fire if the download was successful
    // we will save all the data to the DownloadManager
    void FileDownloadComplete(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // error check
        if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
        {
             string uri = ((WebClient)sender).BaseAddress;   // set the key to the base address (url)
             string html = e.Result;                         // save the html 

             // create the KeyValuePair (this will save all the html and be indexed by the url)
             KeyValuePair<string, string> site_data = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(uri, html);

             // add the KeyValuePair to our download manager
             DownloadManager.Add(site_data);
        }            
    }
}
```

---

Now set a break point.  And watch the DownloadManager as it fills up with data.  Here's a screenshot of the DownloadManager, notice how organize it is.   The website/data combination should be very simple for you to understand.

[Click Here For Full Size Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmpuh.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Microsoft Reactive Framework (Rx) for this. It handles all the asynchronous calls for you and can be used to clean up the `WebClient` (which is an `IDisposable`).

Here's how:

```
var query =
    from rssFeed in lstRSSFeeds.ToObservable(Scheduler.Default)
    from content in Observable.Using(
        () => new WebClient(),
        wc => Observable.FromAsync(
           () => wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(rssFeed, UriKind.Absolute))))
    select new { rssFeed, content };

query.Subscribe(result =>
{
    // do something with each
    // `result.rssFee` & `result.content`
});
```

Rx is basically an asynchronous LINQ query that uses Observables rather than Enumerables.